# Previous year revenue - no DATE table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following table (revenue for current and previous years):

| YEARMONTH | REVENUE |
| --- | --- |
| 202201 | 1000 |
| 202202 | 1200 |
| 202203 | 1100 |
| 202204 | 900 |
| 202205 | 1000 |
| 202206 | 1200 |
| 202207 | 1300 |
| 202208 | 1200 |
| 202209 | 1100 |
| 202210 | 800 |
| 202211 | 1000 |
| 202212 | 1400 |
| 202301 | 900 |
| 202302 | 1000 |
| 202303 | 1000 |
| 202304 | 900 |
| 202305 | 1200 |
| 202306 | 1300 |
| 202307 | 1200 |
| 202308 | 1100 |

and want to have additional column with revenue from previous year:

| YEARMONTH | REVENUE | PY_REVENUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202201 | 1000 |  |
| 202202 | 1200 |  |
| 202203 | 1100 |  |
| 202204 | 900 |  |
| 202205 | 1000 |  |
| 202206 | 1200 |  |
| 202207 | 1300 |  |
| 202208 | 1200 |  |
| 202209 | 1100 |  |
| 202210 | 800 |  |
| 202211 | 1000 |  |
| 202212 | 1400 |  |
| 202301 | 900 | 1000 |
| 202302 | 1000 | 1200 |
| 202303 | 1000 | 1100 |
| 202304 | 900 | 900 |
| 202305 | 1200 | 1000 |
| 202306 | 1300 | 1200 |
| 202307 | 1200 | 1300 |
| 202308 | 1100 | 1200 |

The DAX function `SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR()` seems to be the best try to find the solution but I cannot get it. As you can see I do not have DATE table and revenue in table is already aggregated. I tried to create DATE column as date type containing the first day of `YEARMONTH` month column and use it in:

```
PY_REVENUE = CALCULATE(SUM[REVENUE],SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR([DATE])
```

but it does not work. Dates in DATE table have to be continuous.

Comment: https://dax.guide/sameperiodlastyear/

Comment: Time intelligence functions require a date table.

Comment: Additional remark: If a “static” solution is enough and you don’t fancy a dedicated date table, you could also solve it with power query instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Davide suggests, your formula requires the presence of an actual date table, not this "yearmonth" type integer.

To solve your problem, just add a calculated column:

```
PY_REVENUE = LOOKUPVALUE ( 'Table'[REVENUE], 'Table'[YEARMONTH] , [YEARMONTH] - 100 )
```

[image]

Comment: Simple solution - nice work.